# How to search for files in Windows 7+ like you could in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, search, file-search

I have a couple questions about searching for files on Windows 7.  I find the XP method much easier than this new Windows 7 search.  Note: I am only concerned about finding files whose names match a search term, not all files *containing* the search term.

- Is there a way to search just by filename?  When I use the search it seems to be searching *within* files and returning instances where the name of the file is used.  Example: I have a whole web directory and want to find the javascript files.  But if I enter `myjavascript.js` in the search, it also returns all the html files which reference the javascript file.  This is both slow and difficult to actually find the reference to the file.
- Is there a way to search for an exact match?  The search seems to implicitly use wildcards.  For instance, say I have a bunch of files in a folder: `file1.txt`, `file11.txt`, `file12.txt`, and `file13.txt`.  If I enter `file1.txt` in the searcher it returns instances as if I were using a wild card `file1*.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell or DOS =)

Comment: PowerShell is a great suggestion.  A lot of people think PowerShell is just in Windows Server 2008, but it is in Windows 7 too.  Also really helpful if you are coming from Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at some third party search engine's. Just Google something like Windows 7 Search replacement.

http://goffconcepts.com/products/filesearchex/

Answer (score 0):

I too miss the days of XP search. Still, try [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) Search.

Freeware, runs on Windows 2000, XP, 2003 and Vista and Windows 7.

Also, from the [FaQ](http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php):

> 1.3 Does Everything search file contents?
>
> > No, "Everything" does not search file contents, only file and folder names.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer to (at least) the first part of your question is to type `filename:myjavascript.js` into the search box. As to the second part, what happens if you type `filename:"file1.txt"` (i.e., enclose the filename in quotation marks)?